# Why use subjunctive form of a verb in this context?

Tags: subjuntivo

Today when I was reading an article written in Spanish, I encountered the following sentense (source: [ESPN.com in Argentina](http://www.espn.com.ar/news/story/_/id/2355703/cerca-un-cambio-por-josh-hamilton), titled *Cerca un cambio por Josh Hamilton*):

> Los Angelinos le debe a Hamilton $83 millones por las tres temporadas finales de su contrato de cinco años y $125 millones que firmara luego de haber jugado para Texas de 2008 al 2012.

I think this sentence translates into English something like this:

> The Angels are obliged to pay $83M to Hamilton for the last three years of their 5 years, $125M contract, which was signed after him playing for the Rangers during 2008 to 2012.

However, why is *firmar* formed to the past subjunctive here? I learned that the subjunctive mood should be used when the main clause does not express facts or include uncertainty or subjectivity. But the main clause here, *su contract de cinco años y $125 millones*, is the fact, right?

I know why *firmar* is used with the past particle; the contract *was* already concluded. Just want to know why it has to be in the subjunctive mood.

Answer (score 8):

It's a *stylistic form* which replaces the pluperfect or perfect tenses. It appears mainly in adjectival clauses. It isn't common in normal conversation.

---

Es una forma *estilística* que reemplaza al pretérito pluscuamperfecto de indicativo o al pretérito perfecto simple. Se usa mucho en Argentina; creo que poco en otros lugares.

La excelente **hispanoteca.eu** da una explicación muy completa: http://hispanoteca.eu/Gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Imperfecto%20de%20subjuntivo%20-%20formas%20-ra%20y%20-se.htm

> La forma en –ra puede tener **valor estilístico** en sustitución del pretérito pluscuamperfecto de indicativo o del pretérito perfecto simple. Este empleo predomina en los textos literarios primitivos.
>
> «A medida que va adquiriendo significación subjuntiva, esta forma es sustituida por “había” más participio, el cual, como tiempo compuesto, hacía más visible el carácter perfectivo de la acción. En el siglo XIV el número de casos del subjuntivo se equilibra con los del indicativo. Desde el siglo XV se convirtió en mera variante del pretérito perfecto simple o del imperfecto de indicativo, si bien predomina en general el empleo subjuntivo, hasta que llega a ser prácticamente esporádico su uso como tiempo del indicativo en el siglo XVII. Los escritores de fines del siglo XVIII y los románticos, por imitación de los textos antiguos y especialmente del Romancero, restauran el uso primitivo en muchos casos, sin que por ello se debilite el empleo subjuntivo fuertemente consolidado. Esta restauración literaria, ajena a la lengua hablada, persiste hasta nuestros días, especialmente en escritores gallegos, cuya lengua regional conserva vivo, como el portugués, el sentido latino de AMAVERAM.» [Urrutia, o. cit., 268]
>
> Este era el valor etimológico de esta forma se emplea hoy en día cada vez menos en la literatura creativa, pero se sigue empleando en redacciones de periódicos y emisoras de radio y televisión, donde se la considera más elegante.
>
> Aparece normalmente en oraciones temporales y adjetivas sustituyendo al pretérito pluscuamperfecto de indicativo y al pretérito perfecto simple.
>
> Ejemplos:  *imperfecto de subjuntivo en –ra > pluscuamperfecto de indicativo*
>
> - Entró el la ciudad por el mismo lugar que lo ***hiciera*** el día anterior el legado del Papa.
> - Ha transcurrido un mes desde que ***visitara*** Rusia el rey Juan Carlos.

etcétera.

Comment: Es común en el noroeste de España por influencia del gallego y del asturiano: ambos preservan el significado original de la flexión como el pretérito pluscuamperfecto simple. Y, también, en los textos periódicos (sobre todo en la locución *según dijera/indicara*)

Comment: Could you answer it in English? I wonder why people here want to answer in Spanish; this is not the case in Chinese or Japanese Language Stack Exchange...

Comment: @Gardecolo - I put the main answer in English now. The reason why people answer in Spanish is that Spanish is the preferred language of this site when all participants understand it, and, in this case, given the text you are translating and your question, it looked as if you could easily understand the simple Spanish sentence that my answer is.  (The source is maybe more difficult to understand, but I'm not going to translate that...)