# Subjunctive for actual past event

Tags: verbos, subjuntivo, tiempos-verbales

This is from *Crónica de una muerte anunciada* by Gabriel García Márquez.

> No existía clasificación alguna en los archivos, y más de un siglo de expedientes estaban amontonados en el suelo del decrépito edificio colonial que **fuera** por dos días el cuartel general de Francis Drake.

Here is the corresponding part in the English version.

> There was no classification of files whatever and more than a century of cases were piled up on the floor of the decrepit colonial building that had been Sir Francis Drake’s headquarters for two days.

If the building was indeed Francis Drake’s headquarters, I don’t understand why the subjunctive is used in the bold part. How is it different in meaning from the following alternative with the indicative?

> … en el suelo del decrépito edificio colonial que **fue** por dos días el cuartel general de Francis Drake.

Comment: I think this question (of mine) can be closed as a duplicate of this: [Why use subjunctive form of a verb in this context?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/12551/28954)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En el apartado 24.2 de la *Nueva gramática de la lengua española* de la RAE se explica esta particularidad:

> El pretérito imperfecto de subjuntivo (CANTARA o CANTASE) es el tiempo más complejo del modo subjuntivo, tanto por los contextos sintácticos en los que se usa como por la variedad de los significados que expresa.
> La variante en –ra del imperfecto procede del pluscuamperfecto de indicativo latino (amaveram ‘había amado’), mientras que la variante en –se procede del pluscuamperfecto de subjuntivo latino (amavissem ‘hubiera amado’). Esta última forma sustituyó a su vez a amarem, que era originalmente pretérito imperfecto de subjuntivo. La sustitución de amarem por amavissen empezó por darse en contextos modales, en especial condicionales, lo que anticipaba el importante cambio gramatical que CANTARA experimentó en la historia del español.

En el ejemplo, se trata de un caso que cumple la función del pretérito pluscuamperfecto de indicativo, **había sido**, y no del pretérito perfecto de indicativo, **fue**. Es decir, que equivale a:

> … en el suelo del decrépito edificio colonial que **había sido** por dos días el cuartel general de Francis Drake.

Por eso, la traducción al inglés es correcta: **had been** ("había sido").

---

**Otros ejemplos en la literatura**

Está forma verbal del subjuntivo que posee valor de indicativo es más utilizada en la lengua escrita, y muy poco en la verbal. Veamos algún ejemplo:

> No es ya Montevideo la ciudad humilde que él dejara al partir. (J. E. Rodó)

> Clarín, el buen maestro, fracasó también en la ayuda que me prestara. (Azorín)

> A San Fracisco de Asís le habrá dado un vuelco el corazón en el pecho; aquel pecho abierto al amor de los animales, que en verso piadoso cantara el pagano Rubén. (C. J. Cela)

Comment: ¿Es más utilizada en la lengua hablada or escrita?

Comment: Principalmente, en la lengua escrita. Es raro verlo en forma oral. En realidad, casi me atrevería a decir que es un arcaísmo.

Comment: Gracias. Pregunté porque dijiste “hablada” arriba.

Comment: Gracias a ti, porque no me había dado cuenta. ¡Gracias!